# How to sort multidimensional array and preserve keys in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays that I need to sort A->Z but all numerical indexes need to be preserved.  I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Note: In the `$complex` array, the order of the subarrays does not matter as long as their associated key is preserved and the subarray contents are sorted.

**All keys must be preserved** in both examples.

```
<?php

$simple = array(
    20 => 'Hello',
    10 => 'Cat',
    30 => 'Dog'
);


$complex = array(
    30 => array(
        5 => 'foo',
        10 => 'bar'
        ),
    10 => array(
        4 => 'a',
        1 => 'b'
        ),
    20 => array()
);
```

#### desired output

```
// simple
array(
    10 => Cat,
    30 => Dog,
    20 => Hello
)

// complex; order of top-level indexes (30, 10, and 20) is not important but the key *must* be preserved
array(
    30 => array(
        10 => bar,
        5 => foo,
        ),
    10 => array(
        4 => a,
        1 => b,
        ),
    20 => array()
)
```

Comment: asort? - http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php and uasort - http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[asort](http://www.php.net/asort)

```
$simple = array(
    20 => 'Hello',
    10 => 'Cat',
    30 => 'Dog'
);
asort($simple);

$complex = array(
    30 => array(
        5 => 'foo',
        10 => 'bar'
        ),
    10 => array(
        4 => 'a',
        1 => 'b'
        ),
    20 => array()
);
array_walk($complex, 'asort');
print_r($complex);
```

Comment: @naomik added code examples for both simple and complex. for complex use array_walk to iterate over the array which will call asort over each sub-array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for, the PHP 'asort' method:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: Pointing someone to the php manual can be done as a comment under the question instead of posting an answer.